# how to make a role without send messages permission using discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, bots

I'm making a discord bot but i can not figure out how to make a muted role without send messages permissions. Heres what i have so far:

```
        var role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === 'muted');
        if(!role) {
          message.guild.roles.create({
            data: {
              name: 'muted',
              color: 0,
              permissions: [SEND_MESSAGES, false],
            },
          })
        }
```

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

You should use the client/bot function? like:

```
var guild = client.guilds.cache.get('guild-id'); //<-- Change guild-id to guild id
var role = guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name == 'muted');

        if(!role) {
          async function mutedR() {
          let role1 = await guild.roles.create({
            data: {
              name: 'muted',
              color: 0,
            },
          })
          guild.channels.cache.forEach(async (channel, id) => {
             await channel.createOverwrite(role1, {
                SEND_MESSAGES: false,
             });
          });

message.channel.send(`Created Muted Role For Test ${role1}`) //<-- You can change this message as well

          }
          mutedR()
        }
```

Also, I perfected the code a little bit.
You can also check the code here: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/817529510948896772/841117091754016808/Recording_3.mp4